# 1 second delay when laoding UITableViewController with custom tableview cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, delay

I have scene with UITableViewController designed in storyboard. The table uses custom made UITableViewCell - designed in .xib, .m and .h files. The background color of this cell is **clear** as well as the label and button inside it.

.xib file design:
[image]
real scene:
[image]

When I push from another scene, there is a delay nearly 1 second - between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear of this UITableViewController. I can see this delay only on real device - not in the simulator.

The background of the whole scene is set in UITableView property of UITableViewController - it is an image 640x960px with size of 51kB.

Why is the push so slow? Is it because of the transparency or because of the combining storyboard and xib files? Or what is the proper design in such a situation when I want to have scene like this

**EDIT:**

I run some profiling in Instruments and I can see that there is a bunch of time spent for calling auto layout methods. I'm not very experienced with using Instruments, so what I did was - I run the app, and then I pushed couple times the problamatic controller. This is the result:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I just tried to remove the constraints for the custom table view cell but it has no effects. Any advice?

Comment: None of what you have described here should slow the presentation. Use instruments to see which code segment is causing the slowdown.

Comment: I tried to make some profiling but frankly I'm not sure what it means. See my edit

Comment: Can you post the relevant view drawing code from your `XXXCell.m` files and/or the `XXXViewController.m` ?